# How do POST a Request to this SOAP Web Service

Tags: xml, web-services, soap

I have been asked to work with a vendor's SOAP web service and they have no documentation for testing requests or responses.

I have an example of a `SOAP envelope` and was hoping to use `fiddler` to construct a test that would at least prove I was hitting the service.

I haven't been given a reference to the web service and don't know the address.  The following XML tag is present: `xmlns="urn:xxx-com:xxx:data:v3"`.

I guess I have two questions here:

1. Can I tell from that tag what the web service address is (what is the 'urn' part representing)?
2. Can I create a `POST` in `fiddler` to the address and paste the SOAP envelope in to get some kind of response?

I'm very inexperienced in this area so I apologise if the questions are a bit naive.

Comment: Tell them to give you the WSDL or a link to it, then use "Add Service Reference". You should never use a SOAP web service without a WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

First: The "xmlns" (which contains urn) is the name space used in this web service, and it doesn't reflect what is the web service location is, as it can contain any text you specify (like: xmlns="urn:anything") and it still valid.

Second: you should ask for the WSDL file as there is a lot of details still missing from the web service.